# How to transform List[ValidationNel[A, Option[B]]]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I need a combinator to transform a `List[ValidationNel[A, Option[B]]]` into a `ValidationNel[A, List[B]]` to sequence the validation and, in case of success, flatten that crap.

Here is the code :

```
  def sequenceAndFlatten[A,B](valid: List[ValidationNel[A, Option[B]]]) : ValidationNel[A, List[B]] =
    valid.sequenceU.map(_.flatten)
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `traverseM` :

- Quoting the `traverseM` documentation (`join` is the Scalaz name for `flatten`) :

  > A version of traverse where a subsequent monadic join is applied to the inner result.
- `sequence` is the same as `traverse(identity)`.

So `traverseM(identity)` should be similar to `sequence.map(_.flatten)`, but `flatten` uses an implicit conversion from `Option` to `List` while Scalaz will only flatten monads of the same type, so we need to convert the `Option` to `List` explicitly: `traverseM(_.map(_.toList))`.

A problem with using `traverseM` is that we cannot use `Unapply`, like with your `sequenceU`. We will need to give the compiler some help and specify the type parameters (using a type lambda) ourselves.

```
import scalaz.ValidationNel
import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

def seqFlat[A,B](valid: List[ValidationNel[A, Option[B]]]): ValidationNel[A, List[B]] =
  valid.traverseM[({type l[x] = ValidationNel[A, x]})#l, B](_.map(_.toList))
```

Which gives the same result as your `sequenceAndFlatten` :

```
import scalaz.std.option._
import scalaz.syntax.std.option._
import scalaz.syntax.validation._

val validations = 
  List(1.some.successNel[String], 2.some.successNel, none[Int].successNel)

sequenceAndFlatten(validations)
// scalaz.ValidationNel[String,List[Int]] = Success(List(1, 2))

seqFlat(validations)
// scalaz.ValidationNel[String,List[Int]] = Success(List(1, 2))
```